# How do I deal with a stuck bounce/email-to-activity queue?

Tags: civimail, bounce, bounce-processing

I'm using a traditional mail account for bounce processing.  I have an email that causes the Scheduled Job to fail.  How can I address this?

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.

- If you have access to the bounce mailbox, log in manually and move the problematic email to the "CiviMail.ignored" folder (or just delete it).
- If you don't have access to the bounce mailbox (e.g. it's on Google, and you only have the CiviCRM app password), find this snippet of code in `CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php`:

```
    // process fifty at a time, CRM-4002
    while ($mails = $store->fetchNext(MAIL_BATCH_SIZE)) {
      foreach ($mails as $key => $mail) {
```

Directly after the `foreach` line, put this line in:

```
$store->markIgnored($key); die;
```

Then manually run the Bounced Messages scheduled job.  The job will move the next email (which will be the "stuck" one) to `CiviMail.ignored`.  Then remove the line and on the next run mail will continue as usual.